# One of the turn signals does not stay on

Tags: electrical, turn-signal

My bike's turn signals supposed to be on as default while both riding and parking. I don't know how that thing is called in English so I put a promotional photo. [image: a] as you can see both turn signals are on while riding and blinkers work via turning off and on in a constant rate. Recently one of the signal's decided to not work that way. Light bulb is fine and if I try to signal, it will but it does not stay on as I ride. I couldn't find any relevant information in the service manual either. What may be the cause of the problem? The following is the electrical diagram of an older model which supposed to have the same turn light property. [image: wiring diagram]

Comment: Probably a connection issue with the unit that controls the permanent on - you could do this with a couple of relays and a handfull of diodes...

Comment: @SolarMike Do you know the name of the unit? Or a more technical term to describe either the unit or the problem? so that I can google better. Thanks

Comment: Is there more to the diagram? The wires from the bulb you highlight go to a junction block and no further... so I can’t track a specific unit, unless it is part of the ecm...

Comment: @SolarMike it seems like it. I can send you the manual if you want but this is all  I could find with regards to wiring.

Comment: @SolarMike - It appears the junction block is the ground (earth). The "G" wire from the bulb goes to the right side of the Junction box. It has two separate "junctions". The right side connects via the far right wire down through the ground at the regulator/rectifier over to frame ground 1.  I don't see anywhere else where it is grounded. To the OP: This is an intermittent problem. Are you sure the bulb is good and doesn't have a loose filament? I've seen them reconnect and work intermittently like you describe.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the right bottom part of the picture indicates "G" means green :). Also yes, I realized it was a bulb issue. Just as I came back to end the discussion I saw your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was (in this case) the lightbulb. The lightbulbs contain 2 sets of filaments. One is for blinking and other is to stay on while the signal is not blinking. This is probably because they didn't want to reduce the lifespan of the blinking part as it is crucial. As paulster2 mentioned they were working intermittently and that there was no visible break in the filaments. My, for the lack of a better word, the conclusion is merely a result of swapping left and right bulbs.